# Windows Phone Application Certification failure if Exception Handled

Tags: exception, windows-phone-8

I am developing for Windows Phone. When an exception is thrown in code and I handle it and present a particular message to the user about some problem in a way user can understand. I want to ask is there any chances of my application certification failure if I catch an exception and do the same???

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't fail cert per-se but it could fail if your application got in such a mess due to the exception that it didn't work anymore. There are some exceptions you can't catch anyway (`OutOfMemoryException` for example if I recall correctly)